# Matrix Multiplication Keeps Giving Me The Right Answer With My Math Being Done Backwards

Tags: math, opengl, camera, matrix-multiplication

I been working with openGL and finally been on messing with some shaders.

My issue appeared when I was trying to get this tiger on the screen. I kept seeing nothing. So i decided to joke around and flip my math from

Model * CameraView * CameraProjection and did it backwards CameraProjection * CameraView * Model

I knew it was obvious the answer would not be the same. But once I ran the code, my model appeared on screen doing exactly what it needed to do.

On my side all I do is pass it the matrices I do all the proper placement calculations in the shader.

Here are the 3 matrices I'm using:

**Model World Position**

```
1.0,  0.0,  -0.03, 0.0,
0.0,  1.0,   0.0,  0.0,
0.03, 0.0,   1.0,  0.0,
1.0, -3.0, -10.0,  1
```

**Camera View**

```
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
```

**Camera Projection**

```
2.37, 0.0,   0.0,   0.0,
0.0,  3.17,  0.0,   0.0,
0.0,  0.0,  -1.0,  -1.0,
0.0,  0.0,  -0.02,  0.0
```

My Result Matrices Are:
*(in case you guys didn't want to do them out)*

**MVP**

```
2.38,  0.0,    0.0,   0.0,
0.0,   3.17,  -0.03, -0.03,
0.02, -0.095, -1.0,  -1.0,
2.38, -9.51,  36.1,  36.1
```

**PVM**

```
 2.38, 0.0,  -0.017,   0.0,
 0.02, 3.17,  3.17,    0.0,
-0.82, 3.33, 35.03,   -1.0,
 0.0,  0.0,   0.0,     0.0
```

the math is actually calculated in my shader. It's an openGL shader.

Answer (score 4):

That's because "Model * CameraView * CameraProjection" *is backwards*. For column-major canonical matrices, the rightmost transforms come *first*. The model-space position goes on the far right, then you multiply it by the model-to-world matrix, followed by the world-to-camera, followed by the camera-to-projection. From right to left.

Comment: I'm assuming its because its OpenGL? that this behaves this way? Seeing as in directX my original setup worked? >.<